# unresolved external symbol for __declspec(dllimport) when using dll to export class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline, dllimport, dllexport

I want to define a derived class based on a dll exported class. The base class is defined in Project A, and the derived class is in Project B.

Firstly, in Project A, preprocessor MYDLL_BUILD is defined. And I use a header file to specify export/import:

```
    #if !defined(MYDLL_BUILD)
    #   pragma comment(lib, "myDll.lib")
    #endif

    #if defined(MYDLL_BUILD)
    #   define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #   define MYDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
```

Then I define the base class:

```
class MYDLL_API DllObject
{
public:
    virtual ~DllObject() {}
protected:
    DllObject() { m_count = 3; }
private:
    int m_count;
};
```

In Project B, the preprocessor MYDLL_BUILD is not defined. Here is the derived class:

```
class MyClass : public DllObject
{
public:
    ~MyClass(){}
    MyClass() { m_data = 20; }
private:
    int m_data;
};
```

I have included the dll and lib file, but still I get the unresolved external symbol error:

```
2>Test_Entry.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall ADAI::DllObject::~DllObject(void)" (__imp_??1DllObject@ADAI@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall MyClass::~MyClass(void)" (??1MyClass@@UAE@XZ)
2>Test_Entry.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: __thiscall ADAI::DllObject::DllObject(void)" (__imp_??0DllObject@ADAI@@IAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall MyClass::MyClass(void)" (??0MyClass@@QAE@XZ)
2>c:\Users\Adai\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test_Main\Debug\Test_Main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I searched online, most of the answers claim that the lib is missing. But those instructions do not solve my problem.

When I change

```
    class MYDLL_API DllObject
```

to

```
    class __declspec(dllexport) DllObject
```

The solution compiles with no error. I really do not understand the reason. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems `MYDLL_API` is not being defined in Project A as you're expecting it to. Get VS to generate a preprocessed version of the file that DllObject is defined in (right click on the file, go to properties, expand C/C++ and look in the preprocessor options). Make sure the output contains `class __declspec(dllexport) DllObject` and not `class __declspec(dllimport) DllObject`

Comment: Those linker errors cannot be generated for the code snippet you posted.  You wrote the code in the header file.  So when you #include it, there's no dependency at all on the DLL's .lib.  In case we're not looking at the real code, it simply sounds like you somehow didn't #define MYDLL_BUILD properly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The DllObject has only a header file, there is no cpp file. I cannot generate a preprocessed file for DllObject. The preprocessor MYDLL_BUILD is defined in the properties of Project A. The codes I pasted above are real codes, but it's only the part I think related to the error message.

Comment: Update: I add DllObject.cpp to generate the preprocessed file. The output does contain class __declspec(dllexport) DllObject. However, the errors are still the same. Do I miss something?

Comment: Update: I add a function in DllObject.h and implement it in DllObject.cpp. Nothing else has been changed, and the settings are the same as well. Then it compiles successfully.

   // DllObject.h
   MYDLL_API int foo(int n);

   class MYDLL_API DllObject
    {
    public:
        virtual ~DllObject() {}
    protected:
        DllObject() { m_count = 3; }
    private:
        int m_count;
    };

   // DllObject.cpp
   int foo(int n)
   { return 0; }

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem and hitting my keyboard not understanding why it is happening :(

Comment: @CygnusX1 Me too, basically, very slight difference in the decoration.  (Although for me it's hair pulling more than keyboard hitting)

Comment: I was too.  In my case, it was caused by the DLL being compiled with the `UNICODE` macro, but not the executables that were linking with it.

Comment: I just had the same problem: the project that defined the original class was, in fact, ... not built. It is one of the many projects I rarely change, so it was unloaded. I failed to make the connection for some time because the function is inline.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is inlining.

In short, to make inline functions possible C++ must allow the same definition of function to be included and compiled in multiple compilation units (basically .cpp files) without causing errors. Compiler can, but doesn't have to emit code for any of this definitions. Then linker is allowed to chose one copy.

This complicates dll creation because you need to export exactly one copy but compiler doesn't know which copy is the right one. In this case by adding some code to DllObject.cpp you made the compiler emit code for `DllObject` and linker had some copy of `DllObject::~DllObject` to export.

I cannot give you more detailed explanation of your particular case because I don't know full source and compilation options for your project.

Comment: So including the .h in a .cpp module wasn't enough to get it created?  You'd think the DLL generation could at the least flag this as an error...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. I was including the `.dll` and `.lib` files from my version of *`DllObject`*, But it wasn't helping.

To fix, What I had to do was add the `.lib` files name to my *`MyCLass`* version's project's `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional` dependencies.

If this doesn't work, You might want to add the `.lib` location's directory address in `Properties->Linker->General->Additional` library directories.