# unresolved external symbol __declspec(dllimport) + static initialize c++17

Tags: c++

i have compile libmodplug library. and i have couple change.
but it has error in static inline initialize. i use c++17

in stdafx.h

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
# if defined(MODPLUG_BUILD) && defined(DLL_EXPORT)  /* building libmodplug as a dll for windows */
#   define MODPLUG_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
# elif defined(MODPLUG_BUILD) || defined(MODPLUG_STATIC)    /* building or using static libmodplug for windows */
#   define MODPLUG_EXPORT
# else
#   define MODPLUG_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)         /* using libmodplug dll for windows */
# endif
```

in sndfile.h code

```
class MODPLUG_EXPORT CSoundFile
//==============
{
public: // Static Members
    static inline UINT m_nXBassDepth = 6;
    static inline UINT m_nXBassRange = 14;
    static inline UINT m_nReverbDepth = 1;
    static inline UINT m_nReverbDelay = 100;
    static UINT gnReverbType;
    static inline UINT m_nProLogicDepth = 12;
    static inline UINT m_nProLogicDelay = 20;
    static inline UINT m_nStereoSeparation = 128;
    static inline UINT m_nMaxMixChannels = 32;
    static inline LONG m_nStreamVolume = 0x8000;
    static inline DWORD gdwSysInfo=0;
    static inline DWORD gdwSoundSetup =0;
    static inline DWORD gdwMixingFreq = 44100;
    static inline DWORD gnBitsPerSample = 16;
    static inline DWORD gnChannels = 1;
    static inline UINT gnAGC = AGC_UNITY;
    static inline UINT gnVolumeRampSamples = 64;
    static inline UINT gnVUMeter = 0;
    static inline UINT gnCPUUsage = 0;
    static inline LPSNDMIXHOOKPROC gpSndMixHook = NULL;
    static inline PMIXPLUGINCREATEPROC gpMixPluginCreateProc = NULL;
```

then in fastmix.cpp

```
// Should we mix this channel ?
        UINT naddmix;
        if (((nchmixed >= m_nMaxMixChannels) && (!(gdwSoundSetup & SNDMIX_DIRECTTODISK)))
         || ((!pChannel->nRampLength) && (!(pChannel->nLeftVol|pChannel->nRightVol))))
        {
```

raises error:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static unsigned int CSoundFile::m_nMaxMixChannels" (__imp_?m_nMaxMixChannels@CSoundFile@@2IA) referenced in function "public: unsigned int __cdecl CSoundFile::CreateStereoMix(int)" (?CreateStereoMix@CSoundFile@@QEAAIH@Z)  libmodplug  D:\Study\Open Source\SFML\libmodplug\fastmix.obj    1
```

the question is.why this error happen. because i had initiliaze static variable in sndfile.h file using static inline( c++17) ???

Answer (score 0):

With `MODPLUG_EXPORT` you promise to define and export `m_nMaxMixChannels` in the DLL. The linker trusts your promise and can't find that symbol in the DLL, although it unlikely will use the exported symbol, since it's inline, but the export agreement is broken.

Be careful with exporting inline declarations. Either don't promise to export them, or define them in DLL in one of its sources.

Very similar question, almost the duplicate: [unresolved external symbol for __declspec(dllimport) when using dll to export class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747207/unresolved-external-symbol-for-declspecdllimport-when-using-dll-to-export-cl)